# Autocomplete in Ajax not working?

Tags: asp.net

In Ajax, i am using autocompleteExender in my asp.net application, i write the service for that, when i run that service it is working fine, when i place autocompleteextender in asp.net page and assign properity for ajax autocompleteextender it is not working. this is my code service:

```
[WebMethod]
public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText)
{
    SqlConnection con=new SqlConnection
     ("server=******;database=Mydb;user id=***;password=****;");
    string sql = "Select productname from F_Product
      Where productname like '" + prefixText + "%'";
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con); 
     try
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        string[] items = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            items.SetValue(dr[0].ToString(), i);
            i++;
        }
        return items; 
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
    finally
    {
        con.Close();

    }
```

and this is my ajax autocompleteextender code.

```
<asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" MinimumPrefixLength="2"
     TargetControlID ="TextBox1" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"
       ServicePath="~/Autocomplete.asmx"
         runat="server">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender> 
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"
     Width="213px"></asp:TextBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
[WebMethod]
    public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText)
    {

        string sql = "Select productname from F_Product Where productname like @prefixText ";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = prefixText + "%";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        string[] items = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
        int i = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            items.SetValue(dr["productname"].ToString(), i);
            i++;
        }
        return items;
    }
```

If you find it useful, please mark it as your answer else let me know...

Comment: @Anadnd i am not gettng any thing in asp.net, but when i run serivce it is working

Comment: Enable this method [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] For instance ..[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService] 
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

Comment: thank you for replying, but i am not understand where i have to put this webserivce.

Comment: @Surya sasidhar: If any answer gives a solution for problem then you can accept the answer. That is real way to appreciating.

Comment: @Yank, ya i got answer for my question.

Comment: ya i know the reason also, @yank : To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX,  we have to enable method [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Answer (score 0):

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web.Script.Services;



namespace YourProject
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService
    /// </summary>
    // [ScriptService]
    //[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService()]
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string HelloWorld()
        {
            return "Hello World";
        }
        [WebMethod]
        public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText)
        {

            string sql = "Select productname from F_Product Where productname like @prefixText ";
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
            da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@prefixText", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = prefixText + "%";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            string[] items = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
            int i = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                items.SetValue(dr["productname"].ToString(), i);
                i++;
            }
            return items;
        }
 }
}
```

If you find it useful, please mark it your answer else let me know...

Comment: Thank you Mr. AnandMohanAwasthi