# Autocomplete from PostgreSQL - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete, textbox

I'm making a website with some controls such as text-boxes, combo boxes and labels. To make stuff funky and helpful to the user, i'm thinking of making an auto-complete feature for my textboxes...

However, I want the data to come from the database. E.g. The TextBox is expecting names of hotels, the user types in "H". There should *magically* appear a drop-down *thingy* which contains all the names of hotels in the database.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can do this?

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way..

[Autocomlete list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117459/autocomplete-in-ajax-not-working/8117507#8117507)

If you find it usefule, please mark it as your answer else let me know..